# Reducing Overshoot with CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved in CorePlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using CorePlot in an iOS app, and with CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved I'm getting overshoot and undershoot with some points. Is this just a fact of using this type of interpolation or is there a way to reduce or eliminate this undershoot/overshoot? Here's an overshoot example:

[image]

(I realize I can disable the interpolation, and may go that way-- the curve is generally nice, however).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Core Plot. See issues [#131](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/131) and [#193](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/193).

Comment: Thanks-- I appreciate the quick reply!!